# Virtual player count and max players

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I would like to make the Player Count and max Players something like virtual, so it doesn't has to be the right number. I Thing to set a virtual number for the max Player Count I can use the Method [setMaxPlayers(int mxPlayers) from the ServerListPing Event](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/server/ServerListPingEvent.html). But what about the online Players? And does it also work if I try to get the Players via a query in a plugin?

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to set the number of players via `ServerListPingEvent`.  I'm not sure *why* they chose to implement it that way.

From the doc:

> Displayed players can be checked and removed by iterating over this event.

So hypothetically, you *can* change the players that are there by editing that list (and it will update the count).  So if you wanted to, you can reduce the count (but, I'm not sure if that would be helpful since you can only reduce the numbers).

```java
int wantedCount = 5;

Iterator<Player> itr = event.iterator();
while (event.getNumPlayers() > wantedCount) {
    itr.next();
    itr.remove();
}
```

---

However, the best choice would be to use [ProtocolLib](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/protocollib/) and edit the [server list ping packet](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping) using it rather than trying to use the event.

---

> And does it also work if I try to get the Players via a query in a plugin?

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, but if you mean using `Bukkit.getPlayers()`, that doesn't use `ServerListPingEvent` so changes to the event will not effect it.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I solve it if I want more Players being displayed than there are online Players? And with query I mean, that for example I think TeleportSigns uses a  Query to get the Player Count and Display it on a sign...

Comment: @Nightfighter001 I'll write up a ProtocolLib one.  I'm assuming you're using BungeeCord on that server?  In that case, yes, the plugin probably would use a server list ping.  So TeleportSigns probably would be useable with it.  However, [TeleportSigns is open source](https://github.com/zh32/TeleportSigns), so you may instead want to edit the plugin depending on what you need to do.

Comment: Yes I use BungeeCord :) And thank you I Think my question is answered :)